# Implementing signal protocol with Node server and react using @privacyresearch/libsignal-protocol-typescript

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, encryption, public-key-encryption

So I'm implementing simple client-server application using Node and React using typescript.
I'm using `@privacyresearch/libsignal-protocol-typescript` npm library to implement e2e encryption between React and Node server.
I had a look at their demo `https://github.com/privacyresearchgroup/libsignal-typescript-demo`for the implementation.

so my server side has

```
const localServerStore = new SignalProtocolStore();
const directory = new SignalDirectory();
```

the `createID` method I copied from the demo `https://github.com/privacyresearchgroup/libsignal-typescript-demo` so it's like below

```
export const storeSomewhereSafe = (store: SignalProtocolStore) => (
    key: string,
    value: any
  ) => {
    store.put(key, value);
  };

export const createID = async (name: string, store: SignalProtocolStore, directory:SignalDirectory) => {
    const registrationId = KeyHelper.generateRegistrationId();
    // Store registrationId somewhere durable and safe... Or do this.
    storeSomewhereSafe(store)(`registrationID`, registrationId);

    const identityKeyPair = await KeyHelper.generateIdentityKeyPair();
    // Store identityKeyPair somewhere durable and safe... Or do this.
    storeSomewhereSafe(store)("identityKey", identityKeyPair);

    const baseKeyId = Math.floor(10000 * Math.random());
    const preKey = await KeyHelper.generatePreKey(baseKeyId);
    store.storePreKey(`${baseKeyId}`, preKey.keyPair);

    const signedPreKeyId = Math.floor(10000 * Math.random());
    const signedPreKey = await KeyHelper.generateSignedPreKey(
        identityKeyPair,
        signedPreKeyId
    );
    store.storeSignedPreKey(signedPreKeyId, signedPreKey.keyPair);
    const publicSignedPreKey: SignedPublicPreKeyType = {
        keyId: signedPreKeyId,
        publicKey: signedPreKey.keyPair.pubKey,
        signature: signedPreKey.signature,
    };

    // Now we register this with the server so all users can see them
    const publicPreKey: PreKeyType = {
        keyId: preKey.keyId,
        publicKey: preKey.keyPair.pubKey,
    };
    directory.storeKeyBundle(name, {
        registrationId,
        identityPubKey: identityKeyPair.pubKey,
        signedPreKey: publicSignedPreKey,
        oneTimePreKeys: [publicPreKey],
    });
    console.log(directory);
};
```

So above was my server side.
So my client side(React app) is like below. `createID` and `storeSomewhereSafe` is same like above.

```
export let localUserStore: SignalProtocolStore;
export let preKeyBundle = null;
const serverAdderss = new SignalProtocolAddress("server", 1);

await createID("localUser", localUserStore, directory);

socket.on("emit-keys", async (data:any)=>{
        await getServerKeys(data);
        await startSessionWithServer(localUserStore, serverAdderss);
    });

const getServerKeys = async (data:any) => {
    console.log(data);
    preKeyBundle = data;
}


const startSessionWithServer = async (localUserStore: SignalProtocolStore, serverAdderss: SignalProtocolAddress) => {
    // get Brünhild' key bundle
    const serverBundle = preKeyBundle;
    console.log({ serverBundle });

    const recipientAddress = serverAdderss;

    // Instantiate a SessionBuilder for a remote recipientId + deviceId tuple.
    const sessionBuilder = new SessionBuilder(localUserStore, recipientAddress);
    console.log(sessionBuilder);

    // Process a prekey fetched from the server. Returns a promise that resolves
    // once a session is created and saved in the store, or rejects if the
    // identityKey differs from a previously seen identity for this address.
    console.log("adalheid processing prekey");
    console.log(serverBundle);
    await sessionBuilder.processPreKey(serverBundle!);
    console.log("adalheid processed prekey");

  };
```

problem is this line `await sessionBuilder.processPreKey(serverBundle!);`

above line gives me below error

```
storage-type.ts:113 Uncaught (in promise) Error: session record is not an ArrayBuffer
    at SignalProtocolStore.loadSession (storage-type.ts:113)
    at SessionBuilder.<anonymous> (session-builder.js:60)
```

I copied `storage-type.ts` and `signal-directory.ts` from the demo `https://github.com/privacyresearchgroup/libsignal-typescript-demo`

What am I missing here ?

so how can I implement signal-protocol with typescript with client-server program using Node and React ?